# Change QPrintDialog style

Tags: qt

[image]

How can i open printdialog in this style?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That's the GTK print dialog. To use that style in Qt you would need to write your own class and encapsulate [GtkPrintUnixDialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPrintUnixDialog.html) (and link in the GTK libraries)